# Deploying apps in Netlify with Google API key hidden

Tags: api, vue.js, netlify

Hola developers i hid my APIs from google in a .env file in my code repository , pretending to export to GItHub  all what i have done without expose this secrets keys , but as im working with vue CLI , in order to make live this app must to deploy it through Netlify.
My .env file was in this way:

```
VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_GEO=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_LAT_LONG=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

thus then after post it to Git, on my Netlify console iin the show advanced menu just before deploying the site , i just create 3 variables referring to the former 3 ones, like this

```
*key*              *value*
---------------------------------
maps              process.env.VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS
mapsgeo           process.env.VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_GEO
mapslatlong       process.env.VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_LAT_LONG
```

but the site doesn't deploy.
Any advice ?. Is this a correct way of doing it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing the key/value pair like the `.env` file. Making sure **NOT** to commit your `.env` file into your repository.

[image: ```bash]